# My app reboots iPhone on 4.1 iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've upgraded my iOS on iPhone 3G to 4.1 and now I run my app on the device.
Firstly, I couldn't install it becouse Xcode was saying I don't have certification etc. (I have jailbroken iPhone). Finally, I succeeded and installed it.

But know something strange happens....
After I had installed my app on the device I run it.
Then, "cocos2d" image appears on the screen and just a second later device switch off! It simply reboots.

What's more - when the device launchs again and I run my app - it works!

I have no idea what's going on. This app works fine on 3.1.3 iOS (even with the same Xcode - 3.2.5)

What should I do?
Do you think the problem is caused by Xcode or iPhone itself?
Maybe reinstalling Xcode may help?

Comment: Could be memory management. A few words of advice: SO does not condone "gray-area" like pirating or jailbreaking. Also, choose some answers.

Comment: Whoever said SO doesn't condone jailbreaking? It's perfectly legal, per the Library of Congress. http://www.engadget.com/2010/07/26/library-of-congress-adds-dmca-exception-for-jailbreaking-or-root/

Comment: Hmm... I have iPhone 3G, and when I was jailbreaking I enabled multitasking. Maybe that makes memory problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be one of two problems.

It could be a problem with your device.  Maybe something got sort of wonky with your jailbreak.

Secondly, it could be a problem with your app.  Maybe it's crashing.  Have you checked your crash logs?

Comment: Mmm..Nothing special in logs I guess. You can check it here: http://rapidshare.com/files/435962939/reboot.TXT    (sorry for rapidshare link but I couldnt paste it anywhere else - dont know why).  So I guess I have to jailbreak my iPhone once again. Maybe it's gonna help somehow...

Comment: I have jailbroken my iPhone once again and the same sittuation happens.

Comment: That's weird.  Does your app use any type of database?

Comment: It crashes even when I install basic OpenGL ES app which cames with Xcode, so it's not just my app :(

Comment: If it crashes with one of Apple's apps, then something definitely is wrong with your iPhone.  You probably need to make a backup, and completely erase and re-jailbreak your phone.

Comment: Restore, jailbroken again and still the same. It doesnt work on 4.1. I've downgraded iOS to 3.1.3 and it's works.... Today I tested my app on my friend's iPhone 4 (with 4.1) and everything works fine.. So it means the problem is only with my iPhone lol.